# Uncaught TypeError: <function> is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom-events

I'm getting this error from calling a script that has no content except the function itself. I completely stripped down the HTML that is calling it, and the error is still popping up. Here is the code for the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="translate.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="translate" value="Translate" onclick="translate()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

And for the JS:

```
function translate() {}
```

As you can see, this is the bare minimum code possible, and this error is still getting returned. This Uncaught TypeError is the only error being returned. What could I possibly be doing wrong??

Comment: Welcome to the fun world of the id of the element overriding the global variable of the function.

Comment: Don't use global functions. Don't use event handler content attributes.